# Write utility function to get Taxonomy Terms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, taxonomy

I want to have a common usable function which can return Term object.

I thought of

```
public static TaxonomyTerm GetTaxonomyTerms(this SPSite site, string groupName, string  termSetName)
{

}
```

TaxonomyTerm is class of having property id,name. Structure of TaxonomyTerm

```
public class TaxonomyTerm
{
 public TaxonomyTerm()
{
    this.Terms = new List<TaxonomyTerm>();
}
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<TaxonomyTerm> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

I need help to write this to return the instance of this class.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a question or an order for a coder? ;)

Comment: Apology if my language is not correct.What else would i have done so it doesnt appear as order.

Comment: For me it's not really to language, it is more the lack of information about what you have tried so far, different codes you have tried and so on :)

Answer (score 0):

This post covers the basics of [accessing taxonomies in PowerShell](http://seyedketabchi.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/accessing-taxonomies-from-powershell/) - 
in steps -

1. Connect to target site's Metadata service.
2. Access termstore group & termset
3. Iterate through termset items

(Since it's in PowerShell - it can be translated into other languages)

Comment: Voted Up+ helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Supriyo for guidance.I was also trying with similar other resources and finally could get on right track.
Here it looks like what I accumulated.

```
                    {
                    var session = new TaxonomySession(SPSite object);
                    var store = session.TermStores[MyConstants.StoreName];
                    var group = store.Groups[groupName];

                    var termSet = group.TermSets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Trim().ToLower() == termSetName.Trim().ToLower());

                    if (termSet != null)
                    {
                        taxonomy = new TaxonomyTerm { Id = termSet.Id, Name = termSet.Name };
                    }
          return taxonomy;
                    }
```

Comment: I think changing the name 'TaxonomyTerm' to 'TaxonomyTerms' may help in reading the code (it's returning a list). I find 'prototyping' in PowerShell a much faster way of developing solutions since most of the complexity calls are to the SharePoint object model itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy;
namespace EMM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servcerName:10/"))
            {
                TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
                TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores["MMS"];
                Group group = termStore.Groups["SharePoint Group"];
                TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["BCS"];
                TermCollection termCol = termSet.Terms;
                foreach (Term term in termCol)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(term.Name);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original Post:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/taxonomy-term-in-sharepoint-2010/